# What was the first proof that the prime counting function $\pi(x) = O(x / \log x)$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Is it Chebyshev's with $$c_1 \frac{x}{\log x} \leq \pi(x) \leq c_2 \frac{x}{\log x} \qquad \forall x\geq96098$$ with $c_1 \approx 0.921292022934$ and $c_2 \approx 1.10555042752$.

Was it known before Chebyshev? Are there proofs of a different method (before or after Chebyshev) such as using big O of other functions?

Comment: http://www.math.columbia.edu/~goldfeld/ErdosSelbergDispute.pdf some of the references in the bibliography have info related to this

Comment: This is a perfectly good answer. I suppose it lacks detail which I can add now. It is a great article. I have read it before but did not recall it for this purpose. It clearly states that "the first person to show that $\pi$ has the order of magnitude $x
/ \log x$ was Tchebychef in 1852", and the method shown in the article is different than the one I state in my question (which is something I hoping for). The article has the appropriate references although I have not found it easy to find the Chebyshev/Tchebycheff/etc papers in the archives. I would be happy to accept the answer. Thank you.